# Check if internet is available (targetSdk: Android Q)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-10.0

I wish to implement a simple method `isInternetAvailable` in my project, which returns either true or false based on whether the internet (any network) is available right at the moment of this call.

Unfortunately `getActiveNetworkInfo` is deprecated since 21 and `getActiveNetwork` requires minimum API level 23 (mine is 21).

I already read about `NetworkCallback`, but this seems to notify on network changes, I need a method to tell whether the network is available **right now** or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`NetworkCapabilities`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities) like this:

```
fun isNetworkAvailable(): Boolean {
    return connectivityManager.run {
        getNetworkCapabilities(activeNetwork)?.run {
            when {
                hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
                hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
                hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> true
                else -> false
            }
        } ?: false
    }
}
```